# User is logged out when navigating by url

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

In my Angular app I have implemented authentication with Firebase. 
Today I added a 404-not found page and stumbled on a peculiar incident.When the logged-in user types a path in the url of the browser, the user is logged out. At first I thought it happened because the path did not exist but it also happens with existing paths. When navigating with buttons (and using `Router.navigateByUrl()`), this does not happen.

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'enter-lokaal', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'enter-lokaal', component: EnterLokaalComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'lokaal/:id', component: LokaalComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'lokaalOverzicht/:id', component: LokaalOverzichtComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: '404', component: NotfoundComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/login' }
];
```

Core/auth.guard.ts

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationServiceService, private router: Router) {

  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.authService.user$.pipe(
      take(1),
      map((user: User) => {
        if (user) {
          return true;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
        return false;
      })
    );
  }
 }
```

services/authentication-service.service.ts

```
export class AuthenticationServiceService {
  // user$: Observable<User>;
  userEmail: string;
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  user$: Observable<User>;

  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private  router: Router,
    private usersService: UsersService

  ) {
    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState;
  }

  private logInErrorSubject = new Subject<string>();

  public getLoginErrors(): Subject<string> {
    return this.logInErrorSubject;
  }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(value => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('loggedIn', email);
        console.log('Nice, it worked!', value.user);

        this.usersService.setSelectedUserByEmail(email);
        console.log(this.usersService.getSelectedUser());

        this.router.navigateByUrl('/enter-lokaal');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.logInErrorSubject.next(err.message);
        console.log('Something went wrong: ', err.message);

      });
  }
```

services/users.service.ts

```
export class UsersService {
  usersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>;
  users: Observable<User[]>;
  selectedUser: User;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.usersCollection = this.afs.collection('gebruikers');
    this.users = this.usersCollection.valueChanges();
  }

  getUsers() {
    return this.users;
  }

  /*getUserByUID(uid: string) {
    return this.getUsers().subscribe(users => users.find(user => user.uid === uid));
  }*/
  setSelectedUserByEmail(email: string) {
    this.users.subscribe(users => {
      this.selectedUser = users.find(user => user.email === email);
      console.log(this.selectedUser);
    });
  }

  getSelectedUser() {
    console.log(this.selectedUser);
    return this.selectedUser;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's normal. You're checking if the property of the service is valued in a certain way but when you reload the page you also reload all the javascript and that information is lost, at this point: `return this.authService.user$`

The verification you have to do on storage:

```
// auth.guard.ts
...
constructor(private _router: Router) {}

public canActivate(
      next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    console.log('localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')', localStorage.getItem('loggedIn'));
    if (typeof localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') !== 'undefined') {
      return true;
    }
    // console.log(this._router.url);
    if (this._router.url !== '/login') {
      this._router.navigate(['login']);
    }
    return false;
    // return this.router.parseUrl('/login');
}
...
```

Replace this line of code in **authentication-service.service.ts**:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('loggedIn', email);
```

With this:

```
localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', email);
```

When you navigate within the application you are not really changing the pages (it's the Angular routing mechanism) and the property of the `authentication-service.service.ts` service remains valued.

EDIT: Code.

EDIT 2: Try with localStorage.
Read it from guard, instead of sessionStorage.

Comment: I've tried implementing this solution but it breaks the app, I no longer can login

Comment: Edit with more code.
Can you also say to me the console output of this line?
console.log('sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn')', sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn'));
I want to know if you have that storage valued.

Comment: I now can login and use the app but when surfing by url I am logged out. the result of the console logs is twice my email address and when inspecting the app I can see that my email is still stored in session storage

Comment: Replace this line of code in **authentication-service.service.ts**:

    sessionStorage.setItem('loggedIn', email);

And the same when you read in guard:
sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn');

Edited my answer with replacements.

Comment: The problem remains the same when using localStorage. The value is persisted but the user is logged out

Comment: Strange. Can you show me the new code, with localStorage check? Maybe adding an edited version of guard.
What's the behavior when it log out? There are other log out navigate functions in your code? When in guard "if loggedIn" check returns "true", you should have your logged in user.

Comment: All my code remains the same except for the parts you provided

Comment: When logging out, the localstorage still holds the email of the user, however I can no longer enter a component under canactivate (it says undefined)